# String field is truncated after 20 chars in results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying a simple SQL query but the column `Result` is truncated after 20 characters.

```
SELECT  dbo.EXT_Turni.idvuds, 
  CASE 
    WHEN dbo.EXT_Turni.tipo = 'ME3T' THEN ISNULL(dbo.EXT_servizi_tipo.serv_tipo_descr, dbo.EXT_Turni.tipologia) + ' Text Text Text.'
    ELSE ISNULL(dbo.EXT_servizi_tipo.serv_tipo_descr, dbo.EXT_Turni.tipologia) 
    END AS Result
FROM [...]
WHERE [...]
```

I expect `Result` to output:

```
'Testing mission Text Text Text.'
```

Instead I obtain

```
'Testing mission Text'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isnull` will use the datatype of the first argument as the resulting datatype.

Therefore the first column in your `isnull` function would appear to be `varchar(20)`. If you convert that to `varchar(max)` you will get the full result e.g.

```
ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),dbo.EXT_servizi_tipo.serv_tipo_descr), dbo.EXT_Turni.tipologia)
```

[Official Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Although that doesn't explain your ' Text Text Text.' string being truncated because that is added outside the `isnull` function - so I wonder whether you've shown the exact results you're receiving?

Comment: In sql server designer result preview (leaving mouse for few seconds over the data). I tried with your sugestion and now it's showing ''Testing mission Text Text Text.'